# For each observation, find a corresponding centile on a subset determined by factor

Tags: r

Assume I have a data frame like so:

```
df<-data.frame(f=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 100), value=rnorm(400))
```

I want to create a new column, which will contain a centile that an observation belongs to, calculated separately on each factor level.

What would be a reasonably simple and efficient way to do that? The closest I came to a solution was

```
df$newColumn<-findInterval(df$value, tapply(df$value, df$f, quantile, probs=seq(0, 0.99, 0.01))$df[, "f"])
```

However, this just gives zeros to all observations. The `tapply` returns a four-element list of quantile vectors and I'm not sure how to access a relevant element for each observation to pass as an argument for the `findInterval` function.

The number of rows in the data frame could reach a few millions, so speed is an issue too. The factor column will always have four levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(f) %>% 
    mutate(quant = findInterval(value, quantile(value)))

#> Source: local data frame [400 x 3]
#> Groups: f [4]
#> 
#>         f       value quant
#>    <fctr>       <dbl> <int>
#> 1       a  0.51184061     3
#> 2       b  0.44362348     3
#> 3       c -1.04869448     1
#> 4       d -2.41772425     1
#> 5       a  0.10738332     3
#> 6       b -0.58630348     1
#> 7       c  0.34376820     3
#> 8       d  0.68322738     4
#> 9       a  1.00232314     4
#> 10      b  0.05499391     3
#> # ... with 390 more rows
```

With `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- setDT(df)
dt[, quant := findInterval(value, quantile(value)), by = f]
dt
#>      f      value quant
#>   1: a  0.3608395     3
#>   2: b -0.1028948     2
#>   3: c -2.1903336     1
#>   4: d  0.7470262     4
#>   5: a  0.5292031     3
#>  ---                   
#> 396: d -1.3475332     1
#> 397: a  0.1598605     3
#> 398: b -0.4261003     2
#> 399: c  0.3951650     3
#> 400: d -1.4409000     1
```

Data:

```r
df <- data.frame(f = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 100), value = rnorm(400))
```

Comment: as the number of rows could reach millions, `data.table` will have better performance.

Comment: Simple and quick. I used the `data.table` approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `data.table` is faster, however, a solution without using packages is:

Define a function based on `cut` or `findInterval` together with `quantile`

```
cut2 <- function(x){
cut( x , breaks=quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.01)) , include.lowest=T  , labels=1:100)
}
```

then, apply it by a factor using `ave`

```
df$newColumn <- ave(df$values, df$f, FUN=cut2)
```